# Shortest way of attaching multiple DOM elements to one event handler using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, events, event-handling, prototypejs

I need to attach a single event handler to multiple DOM elements using jQuery. I'm currently achieving this using jQuery's [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method. See below:

```
$([elm1, elm2, elm3]).each(function() {
  this.click(eventHandler);
});
```

I was wondering if there is a way to do this without using the each method and closure. I thought I would be able to do something like:

```
$(elm1, elm2, elm3).click(eventHandler);
```

This kind of statement works using Prototype.js but not in jQuery.The reason I ask the question is because after using both Prototype.js and jQuery I have found that jQuery requires simpler statements to achieve the same tasks in almost every area so I assume there must be a better way of doing this?

---

**UPDATE**

After some debugging it turns out that my original attempt to do this using:

```
$([elm1, elm2, elm3]).click(eventHandler);
```

Was failing becuase the variables elm1, elm2 and elm3 where created using jQuery's $ function. So the problem has changed and is why does the following not work:

```
var elm1 = $('#elm1');
var elm2 = $('#elm2');
var elm3 = $('#elm3');

$([elm1, elm2, elm3]).click(eventHandler);
```

yet using DOM the following does:

```
var elm1 = document.getElementById('elm1');
var elm2 = document.getElementById('elm2');
var elm3 = document.getElementById('elm3');

$([elm1, elm2, elm3]).click(eventHandler);
```

Comment: @Camsoft: as you said `elm1 elm2 elm3` were created using `$` (means dynamically), you could use the live function of the jquery for them as i had mentioned previously.

Comment: @Sarfra Ok well it seems I don't fully understand what jQuery is doing here. Basically variables elm1, elm2 and elm3 are function arguments so they maybe be native DOM objects or jQuery versions depending what is used when the function is called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this as short as possible like this:

```
$([elm1, elm2, elm3]).click(eventHandler);
```

When you leave off the brackets for the array, you're calling a [different overload of `jQuery()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/), with the brackets you're passing 1 argument as an array, so you're calling the `jQuery(elementArray)` constructor.

Comment: Strange because this is the first thing I tried. I was aware that the second argument of the jQuery function was scope, so I already tried passing the elements in an array as the first argument but I can't get it to work. ?

Comment: Seems like I found out what is not working. It seems that the above works fine when I pass DOM elements that are instantiated using document.getElementById() but I'm actually passing jQuery versions using $('#elm1') etc.

Comment: @Camsoft - In that case, `elem1.add(elem2).add(elem3)` but I'd look at how you're getting this collection to begin with, can probably shorten it there.  You can also do `$("#elem1, #elem2, #elem3")`

Comment: I would have done `$("#elem1, #elem2, #elem3")` but the DOM elements are function variables and not strings.

Comment: @Camsoft - You can also do this then: `$([elm1[0], elm2[0], elm3[0]])`, but it's less readable than the `.each()` I think.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$([elm1, elm2, elm3]).bind('click', function(){
    // your code here.....
});
```

JQuery offers to even make above code shorter, so you can omit the `bind` there:

```
$([elm1, elm2, elm3]).click(function(){ 
  // your code here
});
```

Comment: That won't work. `$` takes two arguments, an element/selector and a context. The OP had the right idea with `$([...])`. And, btw, `$().click(...)` is exactly the same as `$().bind('click', ...)`.

Comment: You can't call `live` on an array of elements.  It makes no difference whether they're dynamically generated.

Comment: Also worth noting your `.live()` example won't work.  He's using DOM elements, not a selector, and `.live()` operates completely off a selector, read the Caveats portion of the `.live()` documentation for details: http://api.jquery.com/live/